# VBA excell - if-else in the loop doesn't work as i need to

Tags: excel, vba

I’m setting up a simple form containing about 15 fields which at the end are copied and saved in my database (same excel file but separate spreadsheet). Then I need to design a procedure which will enable me to amend existing records. 
I’ve created one which recalls all the data from database back in to the form so they can be amended and then saved. It worked fine but I don’t really know when to put the ELSE for the case when searched record doesn’t exist in the table.

```
Public Sub amend()
Dim spec_number As Long
Dim licznik As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim specyfikacje As Worksheet
Dim formularz As Worksheet

Set specyfikacje = Sheets("specifications")
Set formularz = Sheets("form")

spec_number = formularz.Range("b4").Value

If spec_number = "" Then
    MsgBox "Type the specification number in the designated field: B4"
Else
    licznik = 2
    x = 2

    Do Until (specyfikacje.Range("A" & licznik).Value = "") = True
        licznik = licznik + 1
    Loop

    Do Until x > licznik
        If spec_number = specyfikacje.Range("a" & x).Value Then
            formularz.Range("b6") = specyfikacje.Range("b" & x).Value
            formularz.Range("b7") = specyfikacje.Range("c" & x).Value
            formularz.Range("b8") = specyfikacje.Range("d" & x).Value
            formularz.Range("b9") = specyfikacje.Range("e" & x).Value
            formularz.Range("b10") = specyfikacje.Range("f" & x).Value
            formularz.Range("b11") = specyfikacje.Range("g" & x).Value
            formularz.Range("b12") = specyfikacje.Range("h" & x).Value
            formularz.Range("b13") = specyfikacje.Range("i" & x).Value
            formularz.Range("b14") = specyfikacje.Range("j" & x).Value
            formularz.Range("b15") = specyfikacje.Range("k" & x).Value
            formularz.Range("b16") = specyfikacje.Range("l" & x).Value
            formularz.Range("b17") = specyfikacje.Range("m" & x).Value
            formularz.Range("b18") = specyfikacje.Range("n" & x).Value
            formularz.Range("b19") = specyfikacje.Range("o" & x).Value
            formularz.Range("b20") = specyfikacje.Range("p" & x).Value
            formularz.Range("b21") = specyfikacje.Range("q" & x).Value
            formularz.Range("b22") = specyfikacje.Range("r" & x).Value
            formularz.Range("b23") = specyfikacje.Range("s" & x).Value
        Else
            MsgBox "The product you typed in doesn't exist"
        End If
    x = x + 1
    Loop
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: So you have printed the code and taken a picture of it?

Comment: @ashleedawg - my comment is really not a smartass, I am trying to think about a scenario where it is easier to print code and take a photo of it, then upload the photo to a computer than simply copy+paste of the code. The only scenario I can think of is a German exam (nothing against the Germans, just their IT exams are like this).

Comment: @Vityata - ah ok, I deleted my *smartass* comment (just being facetious, sorry! :) -  I don't get how printing code is at all related to the question, but to be fair, there wasn't enough information for me to understand the question in the first place.

Comment: @ashleedawg - see the history of the editions +  https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFXec.jpg

Comment: @Peter -- oh my goodness, you actually _did_ print & photograph & upload your code?  To save typing it out?  But....  *ah nm*, um, **Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow!** I see you've had an Answer already but either way, **please take a moment** to check out the [tour] as well as [mcve] and [ask].  (Also [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) if it's relevant), all of which will help you ask & [edit] in such a way to _help us to help you_ with this & [future](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) questions!

Comment: @Vityata -- I'm half German so I can poke fun at them. When my mother learned to send emails, she would print 2 copies of each Sent email, one for her file, and the other she would put in a stamped envelope to mail to the recipient... Maybe part of the reason they're running out of trees. ‎

Comment: thank you all for your input:-) and the code which works as I wanted

Answer (score 0):

I think if you replace your code with the following, it should work as expected:

```
Dim licznik As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim specyfikacje As Worksheet
Dim formularz As Worksheet

Set specyfikacje = Sheets("specifications")
Set formularz = Sheets("form")

spec_number = formularz.Range("b4").Value

If spec_number = "" Then
    MsgBox "Type the specification number in the designated field: B4"
Else

    licznik = specyfikacje.Cells(specyfikacje.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'find the last row on Column A on Sheet specifications

    With specyfikacje.Range("A:A")
        Set Rng = .Find(What:=spec_number) 'search column A of specifications for the spec_number
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then 'if found
                For x = 1 To 18
                    formularz.Range("b" & i + 5) = Rng.Offset(0, i).Value
                Next x
            Else
                MsgBox "The product you typed in doesn't exist"
            End If
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: i think it would be a little more readable if you used a for loop inside 
`For i = 1 To 18
        formularz.Range("B" & i + 5) = Rng.Offset(0, i).Value
 Next i`

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 point taken,... thanks. Updated my answer to reflect your comment.. :)